# Use the Axiom of Completeness to prove the Cut Property.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is the following:
"If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A ∪ B = R$ and $a < b$ for all $a ∈ A$ and
$b ∈ B$, then there exists $c ∈ R$ such that $x ≤ c$ whenever $x ∈ A$ and $x ≥ c$ whenever $x ∈ B$. then use the Axiom of Completeness to prove the Cut Property."

So while trying to proof I have come to a point where I have to show that $\sup A>\inf B$ is not true. So the way I tried is, since $\sup A>\inf B$, we can find some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $a>b$. which contradicts the fact that $a<b$. hence $\sup A \ngtr\inf B$.
Is that the right way to show it?

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Okay. Thanks.